# Display list of uploaded file names upon pressing submit button

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

[This is what my upload file & submit button look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxoKc.png)
The white space below them has to be populated by a list of uploaded files (once that submit button is pressed). I know the directory within which they are saved. Is there some way to call and display just the file names within that area?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by the wording but I will give it my best shot. You can get a list of all the files and the names by just reading the upload input's file attribute, which contains an array of files with a few properties including their name. Then I would recommend either making the div that is that whitespace a flexbox and appending the filenames as internal elements to it. I can provide code if needed, but I think that covers the question. Please feel free to ask for clarification!

A rough code example:

```js
document.getElementById("fileDrop").onchange = ()=>{
  let ul = document.getElementById("list");
  let files = document.getElementById("fileDrop").files;
  for(let i = 0;i<files.length;i++){
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(files[i].name));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileDrop" multiple>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ioBdaS! Apologies for the wording, what I meant is that as soon as the submit button is pressed, the white space has to list whatever file that was just uploaded. Would really appreciate some code help as I am pretty lost on this.